# Using grep to find multiple repeating characters in a word

Tags: linux, grep

I have a word such as "interlinking" where the letters 'in' are repeated three times in the word. How can I search a dictionary.txt file using grep to find other words that have two letter repeats three times in a word, such as 'priestesses' contain the 'es' two characters three times.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - please at least describe what efforts you have taken to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Correct, and I've tried for hours using various patterns with the last one being grep -E "[a-z]{2,3}" dictionary.txt | wc -l and even when I remove the wc -l to view the output I notice I don't get the correct results of matching within the words where two letters repeat three times.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Am I correct in assuming that you want to match any word with repeated characters, or do you need to match a specific set of repeating characters?

Comment: @Cyclic3 I want to select any word which has any two (2) repeating characters that appear three (3) times in the word, e.g. "interlinking" has the two characters of 'in' three times = [in]terl[in]k[in]g. I need to find other words in the dictionary.txt file (contains 1,000s of words) where such a pattern repeats (2 chars, 3 times) in each word

Comment: @Anonymous My answer will match 3 or more repetitions. I am unsure about how to add an upper bound. My suggestion, suboptimal as it may seem, would be to use my regex to match all the ones with 3 or more repetitions, and then manually filter out the ones with >3 repetitions. If it only contains 1000s of random-ish words, then there should not be many that fit the condition, meaning there should not be too much work to do.

Comment: @Cyclic3 - wow that was brilliant and worked great thx very much ... I used grep -E '(..)(.*\1){2}' dictionary.txt | wc -l   this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thx very much indeed.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm glad I helped! If my answer was the right one, don't forget to click the tick under the answer to mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for backreferences!

Use backreferences if you are referring to something you have already matched and want to match it again.

```
grep '\(..\)\(.*\1\)\{<n - 1>\}' <file>
```

- `.*` matches any sequence of characters.
- `\(..\)` matches and captures any two characters.
- `\1` matches the first capture group, in this case, the `\(..\)` near the beginning.

Substitute `<n - 1>` for the length of the sequence minus one and `<file>` with the name of the file you want to look for (or omit it to use stdin).

This may not be the most efficient solution, but it works.