# Using grep to find a word containing every letter a maximum of 1 times

Tags: grep

I have a big text file where every word is placed on a different line,
I need to find every word that contains any letter a maximum of one times

(Examples of words I need to find:
fingers, coal, dream, me, peanut)

(Examples of words I am not allowed to receive on output:
test (contains 2 t's), serious (contains 2 s's), zepelin (contains 2 e's))

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472416/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E '/(.).*\1/d' <file
```

With GNU `sed`, one can use a capture group and a back reference in a regular expression like this.  We capture a single character with `(.)`, followed by any number of other characters, and then that same character again.  If the pattern matches, the line is deleted from the input, otherwise it is printed.

Example:

```
$ cat file
coal
dream
fingers
me
peanut
serious
zepelin
```

```
$ sed -E '/(.).*\1/d' <file
coal
dream
fingers
me
peanut
```

Finding the words with repeated characters:

```
$ sed -E '/(.).*\1/!d' <file
serious
zepelin
```

---

This seems to work with GNU `grep` as well:

```
$ grep -vE '(.).*\1' <file
coal
dream
fingers
me
peanut
```

```
$ grep -E '(.).*\1' <file
serious
zepelin
```