# How to search for strings that occur more than once in a line?

Tags: awk, grep

I know that I can use `grep` to search for a string. But what if I want the output to show only lines where the string I search for occurred more than once? I prefer `grep`.

To clarify, I need to print the lines where the keyword appears more than once (i.e. two or above, or at least two). But I do not mean the lines that have exactly two.

Comment: Do they need to be separated by anything? At least a certain length?

Comment: Seems like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472416/117549 could be an answer...

Comment: They can be separated by space or anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using grep to find multiple repeating characters in a word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472416/using-grep-to-find-multiple-repeating-characters-in-a-word)

Comment: @duplicate I don't believe that searching for "repeated characters" will also apply to "an string" or even "a pattern" (inside an string). As such, it doesn't seem that this is a "duplicate".

Comment: @qbq and also None, you appear to have two accounts. You'll need to use the "None" account to edit this Question (and accept an Answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the search string can occur anywhere on the line, you could could do `grep 'str.*str'` for at least two matches.

And if you want to match the string multiple times, e.g. at least three times, you could do `grep '\(.*str\)\{3\}'`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as OP said he/she was "searching for a string". But I'm not so sure any more...

Answer (score -3):

It's impossible to search for 2 or more occurrences of **a string** in a line using grep since you'd need to use regexp constructs to join the "strings" and then the strings are no longer strings, they're regexps. You need to use awk instead, e.g. to find 2 or more ocurrences of the string `.*`:

```
$ echo 'foo.*bar' | awk -v str='.*' '(s=index($0,str)) && index(substr($0,s+length(str)),str)'
$
$ echo 'foo.*bar.*etc' | awk -v str='.*' '(s=index($0,str)) && index(substr($0,s+length(str)),str)'
foo.*bar.*etc
```

Comment: Dear drive-by downvoter - if you don't understand why this is the correct answer then please just ask and I'll be happy to clear up your confusion.

Comment: What's wrong with `echo $'foo.*bar\nfoo.*bar.*etc' | grep '\(\.\*.*\)\{2\}'`. That will match exactly an string of `.*`, twice, properly quoted to be used as a regex.

Comment: @Isaac What's wrong is that it's matching on a regexp and so you had to manually escape the regexp metacharacters to try to get it to act as it it were a string. That's a non-trivial task in general (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001 for how you'd need to pre-process `str` in your answer before your calls to `grep` to get it to work when `str` contains RE metachars) and is convoluted thinking - if you want to find a string then use string constructs and if you want to find a regexp then use regexp constructs.

Comment: OP specifically said "keyword" (see second para of question).  Normally, one does not then use `.*` as an example.

Comment: @sitaram that's a very naive interpretation of the requirements. The OP specifically said she wanted to search for a string - assuming a "keyword" cannot contain RE metachars and so you can use a regexp as if it were a string is a good way to inject insidious bugs in your code, bugs that may not show up during initial testing when the sample input doesn't contain RE metachars or they don't happen to match incorrectly but then bite you later when run on the real data.