# regular expression, backslash and parenthesis in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

From what I understood, backslash followed by a character is a regular expression.

But I can't figure out what this command does.

```
$ grep '\(.\)\1' < exemple
22
88 9999 88
```

```
$ cat exemple
1 1 1 1 1
abc bc fghi
123 45 678
ABC BC FGHI
88 9999 88
```

The dot is supposed to match any character, and the parenthesis match a pattern (not sure about this one) and I don't understand what the \1 does.

Comment: Related: [Using grep to find multiple repeating characters in a word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472416/using-grep-to-find-multiple-repeating-characters-in-a-word)

Comment: With your command I only get this line: `88 9999 88`. Are you sure `22` is returned? Or actually your `exemple` file has that content?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon They are not showing the correct data in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I supposed that (but I was not really sure). And if I'm not wrong their grep command will match *any character followed by the same one*

Comment: @EdgarMagallon That is what the given expression does, yes.

Comment: yes, sorry there is a missing 22 in exemple.

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression, `\(.\)\1`, will match any line with some character immediately followed by the same character.  The `.` matches any single character, the `\(` and `\)` surrounding the dot "captures" the matched substring, and the `\1` is a back-reference referring back to the first capture group, i.e. the character just previously matched.

In your example input, you have a single line matching this expression:

```
88 9999 88
```

Here, the expression would match the initial `88` substring and `grep` would therefore output the line to its standard output stream.

Note that your statement "backslash followed by a character is a regular expression" is a bit misleading.  The whole expression is a regular expression (in this case, a "basic" regular expression as opposed to an "extended" regular expression), and the backslashes modify some characters' meanings.   Had you used `\[`, for example, the backslash would have *removed* the special meaning of `[` (which introduces a bracketed expression, matching a single character from a set) and would instead force a match of a literal left bracket.

A string is not a regular expression because it contains a backslash.  It's a regular expression because you use it with a utility that interprets it as a regular expression.  Even a string such as `hello` could be used as a regular expression (as such, it matches any string containing `hello` as a substring).

Answer (score 0):

\1 looks to be a back-reference to the capture group (the part surrounded by parenthesis). This is useful in situations where you might want to only output a specific part of a match. I used these a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65641590/sed-expression-just-prints-entire-file

Comment: You mean using `\1` in the replacement part of the `s` command in an `sed` script? For basic regular expressions, you can also use backreferences inside the pattern to match for repeating substrings.